# How-To Aggregate Data Based on Columns

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr

I am new to R, and I am trying to figure out how to combine data into a unique format, and then input that data into a postgres database. Here is code to provide an example of the format:

```
df <- data.frame("1"=c("us","fr","us","fr","de", "de"), "2"=c(35, 20, 35, 20, 22.25, 125), "3"=c(105, -67.56, 105, -67.56, 138, 12), "4"=c(100, 200, 80, 160, 50, 18))

colnames(df) <-  c(
    "countryAbr",
    "latitude",
    "longitude",
    "countOfResidents"
    )
```

Here is the current data set:

```
  countryAbr latitude longitude countOfResidents
1         us    35.00    105.00              100
2         fr    20.00    -67.56              200
3         us    35.00    105.00               80
4         fr    20.00    -67.56              160
5         de    22.25    138.00               50
6         de    125      12                   18
```

I want to combine the data, based on total occurrences of a country, taking into account both unique and duplicate latitude and longitude coordinates. I also want to take the sum of residents and combine it. Here is my expected final result:

```
  countryAbr TotalCountryOccurances TotalResidentCount
1         us                      2                180
2         fr                      2                360
3         de                      2                 68
```

I used the count function to get the total occurrences of the country (I think??), but not sure how to combine everything and what functions to use.

```
countryCount <- count(df[,c("latitude", "longitude")])
```

When I do have the final data set, I would like to put it into a postgres table for querying and use on the front end. I know how to do the latter, not sure how to get R data into Postgres table though.

** Edit for clarity regarding duplicate and unique lat and long**

Comment: Suggested dupe: [how to sum data by group in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061)

Comment: using `dplyr`, ```df %>% group_by(countryAbr) %>% summarize(TotalCountryOccurances = n(), TotalResidentCount = sum(countOfResidents))``` gives your needed result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to count the number of rows and sum the number of residents for each unique `countryAbr`, you can use `dplyr` to `summarise` these counts after grouping by `countryAbr`:

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% group_by(countryAbr) %>% 
                 summarise(TotalCountryOccurances=n(), TotalResidentCount=sum(countOfResidents))
```

Since we are grouped by each unique value in `countryAbr`, the function `n()` returns the number of rows for the group and the function `sum` computes the sum over the column `countOfResidents` for the group. In this case, the counting of rows and the sum is over all values of `latitude` and `longitude` for each unique value in `countryAbr`. I'm assuming that is what you mean by:

> taking into account both unique and duplicate latitude and longitude coordinates.

With the data you provided:

```
print(result)
### A tibble: 3 x 3
##  countryAbr TotalCountryOccurances TotalResidentCount
##      <fctr>                  <int>              <dbl>
##1         de                      1                 50
##2         fr                      2                360
##3         us                      2                180
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the data.table package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .(TotalCountryOccurances = .N, TotalResidentCount = sum(countOfResidents)), 
   by = countryAbr]
```

Comment: the data.table package has numerous speed and syntax advantages. When learning R, you should just start off storing tables as data.tables instead of data frames or matricies.